# Using super resolution to improve video quality

Tags: video-quality

Is there any publicly available code that uses deep learning to employ super-resolution techniques to improve the quality of video clips?

Or even any free online software?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a method using AI to upscale images:

if you convert your footage into an image sequence using ffmpeg, you could run every frame through such upscaling.